# Центрированный элемент не становится в центр — как исправить?

Tags: html, css, input, flexbox

HTML:

```
<label class="label">
  <span class="label-span label-span-selected"></span>
</label>
<label class="label">
  <span class="label-span"></span>
</label>
<label class="label">
  <span class="label-span"></span>
</label>
```

CSS:

```
.label{
  margin: 0 3px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.label-span{
  display: block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background-color: #777;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.label-span-selected{
  background-color: #333;
}
```

Когда увеличиваю масштаб страницы (CRTL+), в браузере **label-span** становится криво (при разных масштабах):
[image: расположение label-span при разных масштабах]

Выглядит не так, как хотелось бы, но вроде я всё правильно написал, так что прошу опытных коллег дать советы, как избежать этой ситуации?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, так (я намеренно изменил цвет фона на красный, чтобы его было видно на белом фоне сайта):

```css
.label{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 3px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.label-span{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #777;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.label-span-selected{
  background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<label class="label">
  <span class="label-span label-span-selected"></span>
</label>
<label class="label">
  <span class="label-span"></span>
</label>
<label class="label">
  <span class="label-span"></span>
</label>
```